# How to get callbacks for Facebook iOS SDK Like action?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk

Trying to perform the built-in-like using the Facebook iOS SDK. I've found snippets like the one below but how can I get notified of the requests status? I have no way of knowing whether the request actually caused a Like, failed, and for what reasons.

**Q: How to get callbacks from FBRequest?**

```
// Trying to perform built-in-like
[FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/namespace:like"        
                     parameters:@{@"recipe":@"http://myurl.com"} 
                     HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [FBRequest API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBRequest) the `requestWithGraphPath` method does not make an actual call.

```
//Returns a newly initialized request object that can be used to make a
//Graph API call for the active session.
requestWithGraphPath:parameters:HTTPMethod:
```

The call itself can be made with `startWithCompletionHandler:`.

```
- (FBRequestConnection*)startWithCompletionHandler:(FBRequestHandler)handler;
```

Looking at the API for [FBRequestConnection](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBRequestConnection/#FBRequestHandler), `FBRequestHandler` is a block that is passed to register for a callback with the results of that request once the connection completes. 
In other words, it will be called when the request completes with a success, error, or cancel action.